# Controlling window size of public Wi-Fi connection page

Tags: safari, wifi

Not sure how to reference this page, as I can't find any similar questions, but I'm building a Wi-Fi page to redirect users to once they connect to our public Wi-Fi, and I'm wondering if I can control the size of the pop-up connection page. On Windows, it's a full instance of Edge with an address bar, etc., but on Mac, it's a trimmed down, small Safari window. Is this possible?

Any help would be appreciated.